# How to tell JavaScript function which id to get from a PHP while loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have a JavaScript function which toggles a div to show/hide, it works if I just have the one link that toggles the single div. But I have a while loop which creates several of these links and div, one for each row. But only the first link works. I can add a $ at end of my id for both the toggle link and div, how do I tell JavaScript to look for this variable?

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var id = document.getElementById();
    $('#toggleDiv').click(function(){
        $('#targetDiv').toggle();
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"toggleDiv$ctr\">;
echo "<div id=\"targetDiv$ctr\" style=\"display:none;\">";
```

As you can see, the $ctr helps individualize each link and div, but I need java to identify which #toggleDiv is being clicked, allowing it to toggle the correct #targetDiv.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

'You don't need for all these elements to have their own IDs if you structure your html and jQuery selectors correctly; they can just all share classes.

Something like this could work in a parent/child set up:

```
 $(".question").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".answer").toggle();
  });
```

PHP

```
echo '<div class="some-parent">';
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="question">question</a>';
echo '<div class="answer" style="display:none;">';
echo 'answer';
echo '</div>';
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPCcZ/1/

Or like this in a "next" situation:

```
jQuery('.question').click(function(){
    if ($(this).next().css("display") == "none") {
      $(this).next().attr('style', 'display: block !important');
    } else {
      $(this).next().attr('style', 'display: none !important');
    }
  });
```

PHP

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="question">';
echo '<div class="answer" style="display:none;">';
```

Comment: why `jQuery()` and not the `$()` alias?

Comment: No good reason, copied from an no-conflict solution of mine.  Fixed.

Comment: i tried your both your set up, but neither seem to work - should the "answer" div have to be within the parent div or outside?

Comment: @OmairVaiyani I've updated my answer with a small fix and a link to a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

A naive and inefficient, but usable approach would be something like this:

```
var i = 0;
while ($('#toggleDiv' + i).length) {
    (function () {
        // Copy the iteration variable, otherwise all of the links will toggle
        // the *last* targetDiv instance!
        var copy = i;

        $('#toggleDiv' + copy).click(function () {
            $('#targetDiv' + copy).toggle();
        });
    })();

    ++i;
}
```

A better approach would be to tag all of the toggle link divs with the same CSS class, then apply the same click handler to all of them (`$('.toggle-link').click(...)`).  This handler should look at the target element's ID and extract the number, then find the matching `targetDiv` instance and toggle it.  With that approach, you would have exactly one event handler registered.

With the approach I've given in code, you will have one event handler *for each toggle div* and this may cause memory issues in the browser if you have thousands of such links.  For a small number of links it's probably fine, but consider a different approach if you may wind up with many links.

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event listener to all the links whose id attribute starts with `toggleDiv`. In the event handle function, extract the substring after `toggleDiv`, look for the div having the ID `targetDiv<extracted_number>`, and toggle it:

```
$('a[id^=toggleDiv]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var number = id.substring('toggleDiv'.length);
    $('#targetDiv' + number).toggle();
});
```

Comment: The ID won't actually contain `$` -- it is the beginning of the OP's PHP variable.